# WordPress - Ajax success function giving empty response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).on("click",".pending-post-approve-link",function(e){

                jQuery('#review_post_status').val('approve');

                var globalVar = jQuery(this).find('.review_post_id').val();
                jQuery('#review_post_current_id').val(globalVar);

                jQuery('#post-preloader-'+globalVar).fadeIn(500);

                $.fn.wpjobusSubmitFormFunction();

            });

            $.fn.wpjobusSubmitFormFunction = function() {

                var globalVar = jQuery('#review_post_current_id').val();

                jQuery('#wpjobus-pending-posts').ajaxSubmit
                ({
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',   
                    data: jQuery('#wpjobus-pending-posts').serialize(),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        jQuery('#post-preloader-'+response).fadeOut(100);
                        jQuery('#post-'+response).fadeOut(100, function()
                        {
                            jQuery(this).css('display', 'none');
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        </script>
```

When this script runs, it gives me empty response. I don't know what causing this problem. This is happening in the success function of the ajax `success: function(response)`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might have done some of those steps, but myself I would take this approach to find the issues:

- Use a tool such as Google Chrome console or Firebug for FF to check if your request is being sent to the expected url, and that it is getting an expected response.
- If it is not getting the expected response, the issue is serverside and you should look there. You can also make some breakpoint using the same tools (console/firebug) to see if the parameters which you are passing look as expected (you can check the POST header details instead too).
- Finally you can try placing a breakpoint on the success function to be sure that it gets executed at all and that the response is an empty string, and not something else.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is what i am getting. any idea why the response still empty http://i58.tinypic.com/2bslqw.png

Comment: If the response is empty, you need to check the PHP code responsible for handling this request. Most likely this issue is serverside, not related to the way you handle the response.